# How to open in memory XLS file using Pandas.read_excel?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsx, xlrd

I have a file which I am trying to open using Pandas.read_excel. I get an error like this -

invalid file:

> InMemoryUploadedFile: file.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to open your file with xlrd, then pass the result to pandas.read_excel with the parameter engine="xlrd"

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=myfile)
df = pd.read_excel(book,engine='xlrd')
print(df.head())
```

here "myfile" is your in memory file

Comment: It gives this error : TypeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is not subscriptable